# Nightwatch-xhr waitForXHR is not returning any results

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I am having troubles getting the return back for an XHR call as I need the data from the response.

I am using the library https://github.com/cortexmg/nightwatch-xhr

```
browser
.url('https://somethincool.com')
.waitForFirstXHR('', 10000, function browserTrigger() {
    browser.click('#printStatement');
}, (xhrs) => {
    console.log(xhrs[0].responseData);
})
```

From from what I can tell the first set of quotes after .waitForXHR is a URL pattern. Although I have had no luck figuring out what exactly they are looking for a "URL pattern". I have tried the request URL and some other things, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was that I needed .waitForXHR over .waitForFirstXHR

```
browser
.waitForXHR('', 5000, function browserTrigger() {
    browser.click('#printStatement');
}, (xhrs) => {
    console.log(xhrs);
})
```

Although, it appears there is a bug with getting the responseData :( 
The array coming back does not display this data and the question is posted on their github